# Call objects created within another method

Tags: c#, object, methods

I am trying to refer to objects created in a method.

Here's the Main method.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    //call all cube base details into existance.
    callCubes();

    //Test Output
    Console.WriteLine("Name: " + blank.name);
    Console.WriteLine("Health: " + blank.health);
    Console.WriteLine("Attack: " + blank.attack);
    Console.WriteLine("");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Here's the `callCubes` method.

```
static void callCubes()
{
    cube blank = new cube();
    blank.base_stats(00, "Blank", 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.00); //id, name, atk, def, speed, sp. atk, sp. def, health
    blank.ev_stats(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.00); //atk, def, speed, sp. atk, sp. def, health
    blank.moveSet(00, 00, 00, 00);//move1, move2, move3, move4
}
```

I can't figure out why blank hasn't been defined in the current context when I've called callCubes on the first line.

Edit: https://github.com/Mooseymax/Pocket-Cube/blob/master/source%20cs/Program.cs

Answer (score 0):

You don't declare an object called cube1 anywhere in the source code you have posted.

You could modify your program to have callCubes() return the cube that it locally allocates and initializes, and assign that return value to an object that exists in the scope of Main():

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    //call all cube base details into existance.
    cube cube1 = callCubes();

    //Test Output
    Console.WriteLine("Name: " + cube1.name);
    Console.WriteLine("Health: " + cube1.health);
    Console.WriteLine("Attack: " + cube1.attack);
    Console.WriteLine("");
    Console.ReadKey();
}

static cube callCubes()
{
    cube blank = new cube();
    blank.base_stats(00, "Blank", 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.00); //id, name, atk, def, speed, sp. atk, sp. def, health
    blank.ev_stats(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.00); //atk, def, speed, sp. atk, sp. def, health
    blank.moveSet(00, 00, 00, 00);//move1, move2, move3, move4

    return blank;
}
```

Note that by convention, class names like Cube and method names like CallCubes() should be PascalCased, not camelCased.

Comment: You're missing the `return blank;`

Comment: Hm I can see how that would work for a small amount but how would this apply if I defined multiple instances of 'cube' in the callCubes method? - also ill switch over to PascalCased for future work!

Comment: @juharr: Thanks, fixed it.

Comment: @mooseymax: Return an `IEnumerable<cube>`

Comment: Thanks, Eric, I'll have a look into that tonight and let you know if it worked.

Answer (score 0):

After reading about you wanting to have multiple cubes at a time, why don't you just place the test output in with the method?

```
static void callCubes()
{
    cube blank = new cube();
    blank.base_stats(00, "Blank", 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.00); //id, name, atk, def, speed, sp. atk, sp. def, health
    blank.ev_stats(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.00); //atk, def, speed, sp. atk, sp. def, health
    blank.moveSet(00, 00, 00, 00);//move1, move2, move3, move4

    //Test Output
    Console.WriteLine("Name: " + blank.name);
    Console.WriteLine("Health: " + blank.health);
    Console.WriteLine("Attack: " + blank.attack);
    Console.WriteLine("");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

You can't really state the stats of two cubes at the same time...

Comment: I did think about this and it would work just fine, but although it works for the test, I can't see it working for when I want to refer to the cubes within another method later down the line?  - https://github.com/Mooseymax/Pocket-Cube/blob/master/source%20cs/Program.cs

Comment: I'll update the answer later with this info but, I think you should probably store the cubes in an array and then you can run a loop to go through the array and state the stats of each cube.